# How to recursively fetch data from paginated API then combine into one array

Tags: javascript, arrays, pagination, fetch-api

Below I tried to write a conditional that would fetch a paginated api and then map it to another api that is being fetched. One issue that is coming up is that it's not continue to loop after it pulls one paginated page or one next page. The second issue is that that the data being fetched from the pages aren't being combined into one array. What am I doing wrong or missing?

```
const fetchURL = `${baseURL}?owner=${accounts[0]}`;
  fetch(fetchURL, {
   method: 'GET',
   redirect: 'follow',
  })
    .then(resp => resp.json())
    .then(data => {
      console.log(data);
      const pageKey = data.pageKey
      if (pageKey !== 0) {
        fetch(`${baseURL}?owner=${accounts[0]}&pageKey=${pageKey}`, {
            method: 'GET',
            redirect: 'follow',
            })
              .then(resp => resp.json())
              .then(data => {
                console.log(data)
              })
           return data.ownedNfts.concat(data.ownedNfts)
      } else {
           return data
      }

   const responses = data.ownedNfts.map((ownedNfts) =>
       fetch(`${baseURL1}stats?address=${ownedNfts.contract.address}`)
        .then((res) => res.json()),
   );
```

Answer (score 1):

To manage pagination from api, you could try a recursive like this.

You should have a script with a request loop with increment params, and a threshold to break the loop. You have to manage the request delay from your api with a time sleep or something like this.

This example bellow work in a node env with axios, you can try it and adapt it with your environnement.

```js
const { default: axios } = require('axios');

// Init a bigData array to push new data on each iteration
const bigData = [];

async function fetchAllPaginateData(
    pageKey = 0 /** init by default page index 0 */,
) {
    try {
        const fetchURL = `https://api.instantwebtools.net/v1/passenger?page=${pageKey}&size=1`;
        const response = await axios.get(fetchURL);
        const { data } = response;
        const { totalPages } = data; // Your api should give you a total page count, result or something to setup your iteration

        bigData.push(data); // push on big data response data

        // if current page isn't the last, call the fetch feature again, with page + 1
        if (
            pageKey < totalPages &&
            pageKey < 10 // (this is a test dev condition to limit for 10 result) */
        ) {
            pageKey++;
            await new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, 200)); // setup a sleep depend your api request/second requirement.
            console.debug(pageKey, '/', totalPages);
            return await fetchAllPaginateData(pageKey);
        }

        console.clear();
        return console.info('Data complete.');
    } catch (err) {
        console.error(err);
    }
}

fetchAllPaginateData().then(() => console.table(bigData));
```

Answer (score 0):

I modified the previous answer slightly to be self contained in one method instead of modifying a payload in the larger scope.

```js
const axios = require('axios');
// These outer brackets are "simulating" global variables
//// `API_URL` would probably be configured globally on your request module
//// `LIMIT` might be set based on the current environment 
((API_URL, LIMIT = 10) => {
    // This method could take any structure of parameters
    // Placing them in an object may actually be better at this point
    // Defaults to an empty `combineData` array
    const fetchAllPaginateData = async (accountId, reqSize = 20, currentPage = 0, combineData = []) => {
        try {
            const fetchURL = `${API_URL}/passenger?owner=${accountId}&size=${reqSize}&page=${currentPage}`;
            const response = await axios.get(fetchURL);

            const { totalPages, totalPassengers, data } = response;
            console.debug(`${totalPassengers} Passengers`, '/', `Needing ${totalPages} pages`, '/', `${reqSize} passengers per page`);

            // Here's the secret sauce,
            // Combine data on each recursion and return it at the end
            combineData = combineData.concat(data);

            if (currentPage < totalPages && currentPage < LIMIT) {
                currentPage++;
                console.debug(currentPage, 'of', totalPages, 'pages');

                // Slow down requests so as not to DOS the API
                await new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, 200));

                return await fetchAllPaginateData(reqSize, currentPage, combineData);
            }

            // Send big data back
            return combineData;
        } catch (err) {
            console.error(err);
        }
    }

    // Presumably this would be called from other methods or files 
    // providing the owners account number for the request query
    fetchAllPaginateData(1007).then(data => console.table(data));
})('https://api.instantwebtools.net/v1', 2);
```